# Como descobrir qual das id's acionou uma funçao em javascript

Tags: javascript, funções

sou novato na área e gostaria de saber como faço para identificar qual das id's que acionou a função clicar. Ou se há maneira melhor de realizar esse código, a ideia é fazer um quiz em javascript.

```
     <div id="perg1">1: Pergunta 1</div>
     <div id="resp1" onclick="clicar()">1 - resposta 1</div>
     <div id="resp2" onclick="clicar()">2 - resposta 2</div>
     <div id="resp3" onclick="clicar()">3 - resposta 3</div>
     <div id="resp4" onclick="clicar()">4 - resposta 4</div>
     <div id="return" onclick="voltar()">Voltar</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possibilidade é você passar como parâmetro da função *(dentro do onclick)* o `this` que é uma palavra reservada que possui o contexto de execução do código.

Naquele momento *(dentro do onclick)* `this` é o próprio `HTMLElement`, ou seja a `div` em que o onclick foi disparado.

E dentro da sua função `clicar` você pode utilizar esse parâmetro para pegar o `id`. Ficando +/- como o exemplo abaixo.

```js
function clicar( el ){
   console.log( el.id );
}
```

```html
<div id="perg1">1: Pergunta 1</div>
<div id="resp1" onclick="clicar(this)">1 - resposta 1</div>
<!--                             ^ passar `this` como parametro -->
<div id="resp2" onclick="clicar(this)">2 - resposta 2</div>
<div id="resp3" onclick="clicar(this)">3 - resposta 3</div>
<div id="resp4" onclick="clicar(this)">4 - resposta 4</div>
<div id="return" onclick="voltar()">Voltar</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo muito obrigado! agora vou ver como usarei a informação que me é retornada.

Answer (score 1):

Vai na função clicar(), e se estiver utilizando jquery exemplo,

$(this).val();

Dentro da função, coloque um console.log para verificar.